# How to import a csv file as a table and not as a semicolons (;) separating columns values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

When I use this code:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("path.csv")
df
```

it imports the csv file, but the columns are separated with semicolons (;) instead of bars (|). Example:

```py
first Name;full name;age;salary
jack;Adams;26;2500$
```

This is what it looks like in Jupyter Notebook. I don't know how to import the file as a table with bars.

Comment: Use the optional `sep` argument to `read_csv()` to tell it what character to use as the field separator.

Comment: Use `pd.read_csv("path.csv", sep=";")`.

Answer (score 4):

Your csv file is probably separated by semicolons and not commas, which is why your output looks that way.
Pandas' read_csv() by default separates by commas, but you can specify the separator:

```
df = pd.read_csv("path.csv", sep=';')
```